Apache/2.4.59 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.5 PHP/8.3.7 running on win 10. Access from over router Error 403 but works in local network. How to resolve network?
I have install Apache on win 10 with SSL and PHP. It is working as it should when accessing from the same pc or same network but when accessed from over router or internet it is giving Error 403.
Note: ISP is blocking port 80 so other port "8000" and 443 SSL is being used and this port is tested with IIS and is fully operational. Locally crested SSL certificate.

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Below are the configuration files for apache:
Httpd.conf
Define SRVROOT "c:/Apache24"

ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"

Listen 0.0.0.0:443
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:8000 
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:8081
Listen 0.0.0.0:8082
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName 83.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "C:/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
LoadModule php_module "c:/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:/php"

<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Require host localhost
    Require ip 192.168.0.1/24
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Location>
ExtendedStatus On

httpd-vhosts.conf
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName wordpress
    DocumentRoot "C:/htdocs/wordpress"
    <Directory "C:/htdocs/wordpress">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName smhzaidi
    DocumentRoot "C:/htdocs/smhzaidi"
    <Directory "C:/htdocs/smhzaidi">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

httpd-ssl.conf
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLHonorCipherOrder on 
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server.key"
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>                                  
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName wordpress
    DocumentRoot "C:/htdocs"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache24/conf/server.key"

    <Directory "C:/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/wordpress-ssl-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/wordpress-ssl-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

Server Status:
Apache Server Status for 192.168.0.43 (via 192.168.0.43)
Server Version: Apache/2.4.59 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.5 PHP/8.3.7
Server MPM: WinNT
Apache Lounge VS17 Server built: Apr 4 2024 15:03:17
Current Time: Wednesday, 12-Jun-2024 14:59:06 Västeuropa, sommartid
Restart Time: Wednesday, 12-Jun-2024 14:02:52 Västeuropa, sommartid
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 56 minutes 13 seconds
Server load: -1.00 -1.00 -1.00
Total accesses: 51 - Total Traffic: 841 kB - Total Duration: 32263
.0151 requests/sec - 255 B/second - 16.5 kB/request - 632.608 ms/request
2 requests currently being processed, 0 workers gracefully restarting, 62 idle workers
__________________________________________________________K_W___
Scoreboard Key:
"_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
"W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
"C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
"I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process
Srv PID Acc M   SS  Req Dur Conn    Child   Slot    Client  Protocol    VHost   Request
0-0 5676    0/1/1   _   55  2057    4114    0.0 0.00    0.00    192.168.0.43    http/1.1    83.xxx.xxx.xxx:80   GET /Php_Sql_Connection_Test.php HTTP/1.1
0-0 5676    0/2/2   _   48  3   1806    0.0 0.09    0.09    wordpress   http/1.1    83.xxx.xxx.xxx:80   GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
0-0 5676    0/3/3   _   36  15  43  0.0 0.09    0.09    192.168.0.43    http/1.1        
0-0 5676    4/11/11 K   4   0   1309    0.8 0.18    0.18    83.xxx.xxx.xxx  http/1.1    www.example.com:443 GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
0-0 5676    0/5/5   _   36  1   2196    0.0 0.09    0.09    192.168.0.43    http/1.1    83.xxx.xxx.xxx:80   GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
0-0 5676    0/3/3   W   0   0   1869    0.0 0.17    0.17    192.168.0.20    http/1.1    83.xxx.xxx.xxx:80   GET /server-status/ HTTP/1.1
0-0 5676    0/1/1   _   56  2680    5361    0.0 0.09    0.09    192.168.0.43    http/1.1    83.xxx.xxx.xxx:80   GET / HTTP/1.1
0-0 5676    0/16/16 _   56  2678    6377    0.0 0.10    0.10    192.168.0.43    http/1.1    83.xxx.xxx.xxx:80   GET / HTTP/1.1
0-0 5676    0/9/9   _   55  3800    9185    0.0 0.02    0.02    wordpress   http/1.1    83.xxx.xxx.xxx:80   GET /Php_Sql_Connection_Test.php HTTP/1.1
Srv Child Server number - generation
PID OS process ID
Acc Number of accesses this connection / this child / this slot
M   Mode of operation
SS  Seconds since beginning of most recent request
Req Milliseconds required to process most recent request
Dur Sum of milliseconds required to process all requests
Conn    Kilobytes transferred this connection
Child   Megabytes transferred this child
Slot    Total megabytes transferred this slot
SSL/TLS Session Cache Status:
cache type: SHMCB, shared memory: 512000 bytes, current entries: 4
subcaches: 32, indexes per subcache: 88
time left on oldest entries' objects: avg: 242 seconds, (range: 142...292)
index usage: 0%, cache usage: 0%
total entries stored since starting: 8
total entries replaced since starting: 0
total entries expired since starting: 3
total (pre-expiry) entries scrolled out of the cache: 0
total retrieves since starting: 0 hit, 0 miss
total removes since starting: 2 hit, 0 miss


Accessing 192.168.0.43/index.html or index.php Accessing 192.168.0.43/index.html/wes/index.html or index.php
Accessing 192.168.0.43/index.html/smh/index.html or index.php

index.php
<body>
    <h1>C:\ htdocs It works!</h1>
</body>

<?php

phpinfo();
?>

index.html:
<html>
<head>
    <title>Centered Text</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <p style="font-size: 4rem; width: 60%; text-align: center;">
        (((<h1>C:\ htdocs It works!</h1>)))
    </p>
</body>
</html>

